# Как сделать разброс оружия, а то все пули летят в одну точку

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Есть скрипт на стрельбу в 2D платформере. Не знаю как сделать разброс оружия, а то все пули летят в одну точку. Есть пустой GameObject из которого вылетает пуля.

```
public class Weapon : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform firePoint;
    public GameObject Bullet;
    public AudioClip ShootSound;
    [SerializeField] ParticleSystem GunBOOM;
    AudioSource Audio;
    public float fireRate = 100;
    private float _timer;

    void Start()
    {
        Audio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        Audio.Play();
    }
    void Update()
    {

        if (Input.GetButton("Fire1"))
        {
            _timer += Time.deltaTime;
            if (_timer < 1 / fireRate) return;
            Shoot();
            _timer = 0;

            GunBOOM.Play();
        }
        else
        {
            GunBOOM.Stop();
        }



    }

    void Shoot()
    {
        Instantiate(Bullet, firePoint.position, firePoint.rotation);     
        Audio.PlayOneShot(ShootSound);


    }

}
```

Comment: У вас есть `firePoint.position` - это точка, куда летит пуля.. сделайте ее рандомной в пределах разумного. Если нужно визуально это еще отрозить - `firePoint.rotation`

Comment: А как это сделать? Я попробовал но что-то не очень

Comment: что выдает `firePoint.position` в Debug?

Comment: Есть например такой вариант. При каждой пули рандомно (с помощью `Random.Range`) выбираете очень маленький угол (например от -0,5 до 0,5 градус) и меняете траекторию на этот угол

Comment: Согласен не самый лучший вариант, но решение проблемы

Answer (score 0):

`angle` - это угол разброса

```
    var bullet = Instantiate(Bullet, firePoint.position, firePoint.rotation);             
    var spread = Random.Range(-angle / 2f, angle / 2f);
    bullet.transform.Rotate(0, 0, spread);
```

Answer (score -2):

```cs
Instantiate(Bullet, firePoint.position, firePoint.rotation);
```

Используй тут `Random.Range`.

Comment: Укажите в ответе более подробно, что и как использовать.